# Whats the proper way of reading byte array data into a object

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

So I have this byte array which looks like this

```
[40, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 7, 69, 108, 121, 115, 105, 97, 110, 0, 0, 0, 0, 215, 90, 55, 255, 125, 90, 105, 90, 75, 175, 165, 140, 160, 180, 215, 255, 230, 175, 160, 105, 60, 0]
```

And I'm trying to parse that into a object called `Player` to fill all it's properties such as name etc..

And this was my approach which is a terrible one!

```
var player = new Player {
    Client = state.workSocket,
    UUID = state.player.UUID,
    PlayerID = data[3],
    SkinVarient = data[4],
    Hair = data[5],
    Name = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data, 7, data[6]),
    HairDye = data[7 + data[6] + 1],
    HideVisuals = data[7 + data[6] + 2],
    HideVisuals2 = data[7 + data[6] + 3],
    HideMisc = data[7 + data[6] + 4],
    HairColor = data.Skip(data[7 + data[6] + 4]).Take(3).ToArray(),
    SkinColor = data.Skip(data[7 + data[6] + 4] + 3).Take(3).ToArray(),
    EyeColor = data.Skip(data[7 + data[6] + 4] + 3 + 3).Take(3).ToArray(),
    ShirtColor = data.Skip(data[7 + data[6] + 4] + 3 + 3 + 3).Take(3).ToArray(),
    UnderShirtColor = data.Skip(data[7 + data[6] + 4] + 3 + 3 + 3 + 3).Take(3).ToArray(),
    PantsColor = data.Skip(data[7 + data[6] + 4] + 3 + 3 + 3 + 3 + 3).Take(3).ToArray(),
    ShoeColor = data.Skip(data[7 + data[6] + 4] + 3 + 3 + 3 + 3 + 3 + 3).Take(3).ToArray(),
    Difficulty = data.Last()
};
```

That doesn't feel like a very robust and good way of mapping it, is there a proper way of doing this?

Comment: Did you consider to use any kind of deserialization here? How was source array created?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski It gets sent like that every time from the client.

Comment: is it possible to get a JSON payload from the client? It will be much easier with JSON

Comment: @ejwill Unfortunately not, what is in the example is what I get every time

Comment: @RileyVarga is the byte array encoded text/json or are those the actual values?

Comment: @ejwill Those are the actual values